Cant figure out the name of a sci-fi prisoner transport movie
Ok, this is really bugging me, it was a movie maybe in the 90's, there was a fururistic complex, or city within a very large wall, on the outside of that wall there was desert I believe. A man got convicted of something, and got transported out of the city with other prisoners, like they were banished or something, I want to say on a train, but maybe it was a ship or something else. Something happened and the transport crashed or got stopped, the man escaped and went back to the large wall to get back in, i think?
This is all I know unfortunately, some of the details might be wrong, ive been goggling so many movies trying to figure it out, I might of got some stuff mixed up. The 90s might even be wrong, but the effects and hair styles seemed to remind me of it

This sounds like Judge Dredd (1995)
The movie starts with Herman arriving from a Penal Colony back into MegaCity One via a ship:

Later on, after being in the vicinity of a gun fight and destroying a robot so he can escape, he along with Judge Dredd are being sent back to the jail on another ship which is shot down

Later on, Herman and Dredd both break back into the city through some fire-pipe things:



Ah sweet, that is it, I guess I didn't think this would of been it, I kept thinking of the new Judge Dredd story line whenever I saw it in search results so I ignored it
